# show/hide a div with dropdown value in asp.net

Tags: html, css, asp.net

[image]
[image]

its my code i want to hide div which have id selnumber (when i select form 60/61 and show a text message "It is form 60/61" at the place of div) but when select pan then show the div.

```
<div id="selpan"> 
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlpan" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem>---Select---</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>PAN</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>FORM 60/61</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList> </div>
                </td><div id="selnumber">
                <td colspan="3">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
                <asp:Label ID="add_no" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Verdana" 
                        Font-Size="10pt" Font-Strikeout="False" Text="File Number"></asp:Label>
                   </td><td> 
                <asp:TextBox ID="tbnumber" runat="server" ontextchanged="tbnumber_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add onchange event on dropdownlist and though javascript you can check if selected item in the list in form 60/61 then hide the div else show the div.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="selpan"> 
            <asp:DropDownList AutoPostBack="true" ID="ddlpan" runat="server" onselectedindexchanged="ddlpan_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <asp:ListItem>---Select---</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>PAN</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>FORM 60/61</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList> </div>

<asp:Label Visible="false" ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="10pt" Font-Strikeout="False" Text="File Number"></asp:Label>
        <div id="selnumber" Visible="false" runat="server">              
            <asp:Label ID="add_no" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Verdana"  Font-Size="10pt" Font-Strikeout="False" Text="File Number"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tbnumber" runat="server" ontextchanged="tbnumber_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
         </div>
```

.....

```
  protected void ddlpan_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ddlpan.SelectedIndex == 1)
    {
        selnumber.Visible = true;
        lblMessage.Visible = false;

    }
    else if (ddlpan.SelectedIndex == 2)
    {
        selnumber.Visible = false;
        lblMessage.Visible = true;
        lblMessage.Text = "It is form 60/61";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways you can do this.

You can either use **onSelectedIndexChanged()** event like @Sruthi already said but that will include an unnecessary call to server and take time.

Second and better way to do this is to use javascript **onchange()** event and save both time and resources.

Javascript code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function change() {
            var DropdownList = document.getElementById('<%=ddlpan.ClientID %>');
            var SelectedIndex = DropdownList.selectedIndex;
            var message = document.getElementById('message');
            var selnumber = document.getElementById('selnumber');

            if (SelectedIndex == 2) {
                selnumber.style.display = "none";
                message.style.display = "block";
            }
            else {
                selnumber.style.display = "block";
                message.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    </script>
```

ASP.NET code..

```
<div id="selpan"> 
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlpan" runat="server" onchange="change()">

                <asp:ListItem>---Select---</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>PAN</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>FORM 60/61</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList> 
            <asp:Label ID="label" runat="server"></asp:Label></div>
            </td><div id="selnumber" style="">
            <td colspan="3">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
            <asp:Label ID="add_no" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Verdana" 
                    Font-Size="10pt" Font-Strikeout="False" Text="File Number"></asp:Label>
               </td><td> 
            <asp:TextBox ID="tbnumber" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            </div>
            <div id="message" style="display:none">
            <label>This is form 60/61</label>
            </div>
```

Comment: the div which have id "salnumber" not hide when i select form60/61....its continuously shows....

Comment: it works for me... recheck the code.. there are some modifications in ASP.NET code as well... if you still can't find the problem, take a screenshot of the code and post it here..

Comment: how can i add image here

Comment: @AnkitSharma everything seems to be fine.. post a live link to your project if possible...